# SQL Using Order By in Union Statement

Tags: sql, db2, sql-order-by, union

Please see below code i am struggling with:

```
select * 
from AAA_PROD_XEUSS.P_E_LVR_CQT CQT 
left join AAA_PROD_XEUSS.P_F_OPERATION OPER
on CQT.OPERATION = OPER.OPERATION
union
select * 
from BBB_PROD_XEUSS.P_E_LVR_CQT CQT
left join BBB_PROD_XEUSS.P_F_OPERATION OPER
on CQT.OPERATION = OPER.OPERATION
where CQT.PROCESS = '1111'
Order by OPERATION
```

I am getting following Error:
ERROR [42877] [IBM][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0197N A qualified column name is not allowed in the ORDER BY clause.
Any suggested solution giving errors

Thank you

Comment: Thank you. Error: ERROR [42702] [IBM][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0203N A reference to column "OPERATION" is ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

Take the order by clause outside, and alias all the columns in the select lists of inner part.

(*One of `cqt.operation` or `oper.operation` may be preferred inside, since they're matched to be equal*) :

```
Select * 
from
    (select cqt.col1, cqt.col2, oper.* 
     -- where "operation" column is exempted from cqt list, 
     --  since the table aliased as oper already has "operation" column.
     from AAA_PROD_XEUSS.P_E_LVR_CQT CQT 
     left join AAA_PROD_XEUSS.P_F_OPERATION OPER on CQT.OPERATION = OPER.OPERATION
     union
     select cqt.col1, cqt.col2, oper.*
     from BBB_PROD_XEUSS.P_E_LVR_CQT CQT
     left join BBB_PROD_XEUSS.P_F_OPERATION OPER on CQT.OPERATION = OPER.OPERATION
     where CQT.PROCESS = '1111'
) 
Order by OPERATION
```

Comment: Thank you. What can i do if number of columns is large? Alias all of them?

Comment: @Felix You're welcome. Which of them has column large may be asterisked, and for the other table we need to alias them unfortunately( cqt.col1, cqt.col2, oper.*  without operation column for table aliased as CQT, the table aliased with OPER already has operation column )

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `order by`, but you need to list the columns explicitly.  This is a good practice anyway:

```
select cqt.*, oper.?, oper.?, . . .
from AAA_PROD_XEUSS.P_E_LVR_CQT CQT left join
     AAA_PROD_XEUSS.P_F_OPERATION OPER
    on CQT.OPERATION = OPER.OPERATION
union
select cqt.*, oper.?, oper.?, . . .
from BBB_PROD_XEUSS.P_E_LVR_CQT CQT left join
     BBB_PROD_XEUSS.P_F_OPERATION OPER
     on CQT.OPERATION = OPER.OPERATION
where CQT.PROCESS = '1111'
Order by OPERATION;
```

The `OPERATION` column should be coming from the `CQT` table.  The `?`s are placeholders for additional columns in `OPER`.  This assumes that the two `CQT` tables have the same columns with the same types defined in the same order.  The better practice is to list all columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Db2 11.1, you can use the `JOIN USING` syntax to avoid having two copies of the joined column(s) in the result set https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0059207.html

E.g. with these tables

```
create table AAA_PROD_XEUSS.P_E_LVR_CQT   (i int, OPERATION int, PROCESS char(4)););
create table AAA_PROD_XEUSS.P_F_OPERATION (b int, OPERATION int);
create table BBB_PROD_XEUSS.P_E_LVR_CQT   (c int, OPERATION int, PROCESS char(4));
create table BBB_PROD_XEUSS.P_F_OPERATION (b int, OPERATION int);
```

this select

```
select * 
from AAA_PROD_XEUSS.P_E_LVR_CQT CQT 
left join AAA_PROD_XEUSS.P_F_OPERATION OPER
USING ( OPERATION )
union
select * 
from BBB_PROD_XEUSS.P_E_LVR_CQT CQT
left join BBB_PROD_XEUSS.P_F_OPERATION OPER
USING ( OPERATION )
where CQT.PROCESS = '1111'
Order by OPERATION
```

Will return just one column named OPERATION

```
OPERATION I PROCESS B
--------- - ------- -

0 record(s) selected.
```

P.S. You might prefer to use `UNION ALL` rather than just `UNION` to avoid Db2 having to sort all the rows to remove duplicates

Comment: `USING` only joins the two tables of the left and right of the `JOIN` clause. So there I don't think there is any "risk" of joining other tables that have the same column names. Are you thinking about a "natural join" where all columns of the same name are joined? (That is not supported in Db2). FYI the manual says "This clause joins the tables on the specified columns. Each column exists in **both** of the tables to be joined."

Comment: Wow.  I'm not sure where I got that `USING` or `NATURAL` would harvest all the columns possible; it looks like all major RDBMSs only use the left/right tables.  Withdrawn.